# Data transfer via audio jack

Tags: android

I want to implement an Android app that sends data from one device to another via audio jack.

How can I do?

Are there functions of Android already implemented for data manipulation?
And as for the modulation of signals from analog to digital and vice versa?

Comment: You can start by sharing some code on what have you googled/attempted so far. Why would you want to do that kind of transfer?

Answer (score 1):

Only a PoC suggestion for "beginners": use DTMF to send your data in HEX approach. This simplify the sending side: prepare 16 audio (DTMF) files to represent 0, 1, 2, ... E, F, one audio file as "start" and one as "end". When you need to send string "ABC", i.e. ASCII 0x65 0x66 0x67, sender play "start" "6" "5" "6" "6" "6" "7" "end".

About the receiving side, sorry that you need to collect the audio sample, detect the silent and segment the recorded tone one by one, and uses FFT to get back the frequency pair of each of the tone received; map against that 18 DTMF tones used in the sender, and... you got the data.